# How can I have dots in my 3D diagram? I cannot add the diagonal dots, the slopes are different

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

[image]

I am trying to make his diagram. But I realized that \diagdots does not work due to different slopes with `\arrow{dr}`.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome! Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `dash patterns`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash},
    column sep=1em,
    every label/.append style=black,
    /tikz/every even row/.style={nodes={xshift=4em,red!80}},
    /tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=3em},
    execute at end picture={
    \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {\vphantom{1},1,2,n}
    { (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\X) 
    edge[cyan,"$\phi_{\Y}$"'{black}] (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-\X)};
    \path[red!80!black] 
    (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-1)--(\tikzcdmatrixname-4-1) coordinate[pos=0](aux0)
     coordinate[pos=1](aux1)
    let \p1=($(aux1)-(aux0)$),  \n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)} in
    [dash pattern=on \n1/3 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on
    \n1/27 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/3]
     foreach \X in {1,...,4}
      {(\tikzcdmatrixname-3-\X) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-\X)};
    \path[red!80!black] 
    (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-1)--(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-1) coordinate[pos=0](aux0)
     coordinate[pos=1](aux1)
    let \p1=($(aux1)-(aux0)$),
    \n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)} in
    [dash pattern=on \n1/3 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on
    \n1/27 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/3]
     foreach \X in {1,...,4}
      {(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-\X) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-2-\X)};
    \path 
      foreach \X in {1,...,4}
      {foreach \Y in {1,...,2}
      {(\tikzcdmatrixname-\X-\Y) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-\X-\the\numexpr\Y+1)}};
    \path   
    (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-3)--(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-4) coordinate[pos=0](aux0)
     coordinate[pos=1](aux1) 
     let \p1=($(aux1)-(aux0)$), \n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)} in
       [dash pattern=on \n1/3 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on \n1/27 off \n1/27 on
    \n1/27 off 2*\n1/27 on \n1/3] foreach \X in {1,...,4} 
    {(\tikzcdmatrixname-\X-3) edge (\tikzcdmatrixname-\X-4)};  
    \path foreach \Y [count=\X] in {\vphantom{1},1,2,n}
    {(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-\X) 
    edge[cyan,"$\widetilde{\phi}_{\Y}$" '{black}] (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-\X)};
    }]
 X_G & 
    X_{G_1}  & 
    X_{G_2}  & 
    X_{G_n} \\[2em] 
 X_G^m & X_{G^m_1}  & X_{G^m_2} &  X_{G^m_n} \\ 
 X_H & X_{H_1}  & X_{H_2} & X_{H_n} \\[2em] 
 X_H^m & X_{H^m_1}  & X_{H^m_2} &  X_{H^m_n} \\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use `decorations.markings` (cf. [Henri's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523240/how-can-i-have-dots-in-my-3d-diagram-i-cannot-add-the-diagonal-dots-the-slopes/523248?noredirect=1#comment1323561_523248)) but the version that comes with `tikz-cd`.

```
 \arrow[r,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white}]
```

The resulting code looks indeed simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={preaction={draw,white,line width=3pt},dash,thin},
    column sep=1em,
    every label/.append style=black,
    /tikz/every even row/.style={nodes={xshift=4em,red!80}},
    /tikz/column 3/.style={column sep=3em},]
 X_G \arrow[r] \arrow[dd,"\phi"',cyan] \arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]&
    X_{G_1} \arrow[r]\arrow[dd,"\phi_1"',cyan] \arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]&
    X_{G_2} \arrow[dd,"\phi_2"',cyan]\arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black] \arrow[r,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white}] &
    X_{G_n} \arrow[dd,"\phi_n"',cyan]\arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]  \\[2em] 
 X_G^m \arrow[r]&
    X_{G^m_1}\arrow[r]    &
    X_{G^m_2} \arrow[r,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white}] &
     X_{G^m_n} \\ 
 X_H  \arrow[r]\arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]&
    X_{H_1} \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black] &
    X_{H_2}  \arrow[r,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white}]\arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]&
    X_{H_n}  \arrow[d,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white,text=red!80!black},red!80!black]\\[2em] 
 X_H^m \arrow[r]\arrow[uu,"\widetilde{\phi}",cyan]&
    X_{H^m_1}\arrow[r] \arrow[uu,"\widetilde{\phi}_1",cyan]  &
    X_{H^m_2}\arrow[r,"\cdots"{marking,fill=white}]\arrow[uu,"\widetilde{\phi}_2",cyan] &
     X_{H^m_n} \arrow[uu,"\widetilde{\phi}_n",cyan]\\ 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: enhanced the 3d-like impression a bit with the preaction that adds a white halo to the paths.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty complicated. Why not something like `\draw[decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw[dashed] (-1,0) -- (1,0);}, pre length=2cm, post length=2cm}] (0,0) -- (30:6);`?  Only works for straight lines though.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I agree,  or just use built in `marking`s of `tikz-cd`. The reason why I did not do that was that I originally wanted to do 3D ordering. (The diagram also *is* bulky. Repetitions cry for `foreach` but cannot built in `tikz-cd` at the matrix level....

Comment: @HenriMenke I added something along the lines you suggest. Indeed, at least it looks less complicated. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem is the label of the latest vertical arrows are \phi_n. Actually, the second code has the correct labels, I have used the first one. But I could not figure out how can fix the labels. Thanks!

Comment: @NaghmehAkhavan Just replace `\ifnum\X=4\else_\X\fi` by `\ifnum\X=4\relax _n\else_\X\fi`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have relaced, but there is an error "<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> Paper.tex" ---- (incomplete \iffalse)

Comment: @NaghmehAkhavan I updated the first code of the answer. I really just did the changes I proposed, and on my machine it works. Do you get errors if you run this updated code?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you so much! I copied your new version code and it perfectly works. Is there any chance to the second \phi starts from index 1 instead of 2?

Comment: @NaghmehAkhavan I changed that, and, more importantly, changed the way the edge labels are produced, hoping this makes it easier to customize it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes! It is more convenient for someone like me who is a beginner. Thank you!!